# Calling a function in a .as file from a nested movieclip

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I know there are lots of variations on this question but I can't find an answer that works for me.

Specifically I have some simple functions in a .as file. I've used #include and I can call the functions just fine from the main timeline, but I can't seem to call them from the timeline of nested movieclips.

I have a movieclip inside a movieclip inside a movieclip which is on the main timeline. How can I access the functions in the .as file?

I've tried this.parent.parent.parent.function() and _root.parent.parent.function() but neither works.

The functions are linked through Scaleform to a games engine so I'd rather not use classes as this will complicate things for me. For the same reason I'm using AS2, not AS3 (AS2 is not supported by the version of Scaleform included with the game engine).

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can simply use :

```
_root.your_function();
```

Or if your MovieClip is used directly in the main timeline :

```
this._parent.your_function();
```

And here don't forget that in AS2, we use `_parent` to get the parent of the current object.

You can get all the available included functions in the parent using this :

```
for(var element in this._parent){
    if(typeof this._parent[element] == 'function'){
        trace(element + ' : ' + this._parent[element]);
    }
}
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: Thanks very much; _root.my_function(); did it. I thought that _root just referred to the root of the object containing the code, you learn something new every day :) Will read up on _parent. Thanks again.